# Errors on yum.cron.hourly.conf in new Centos install

Tags: centos, yum

I have a VPS with a fresh Centos 7 install, and am getting mail from Cron with these errors:

```
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: /etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf, line: 1
'update_cmd = security\n'
```

The `yum-cron-hourly.conf` file looks like this:

```
update_cmd = security
update_messages = no
download_updates = no
apply_updates = no
random_sleep = 30
[emitters]
system_name = None
emit_via = stdio
output_width = 80
[email]
email_from = root@localhost
email_to = root
email_host = localhost
[groups]
group_list = None
group_package_types = mandatory, default
[base]
debuglevel = -3
mdpolicy = group:main
```

So it seems yum-cron expects a section header at the start of the file. I have not touched this file - it is exactly as it was (I did not explicitly install yum-cron.)

Any ideas? Can I just add a header? Should I just disable yum-cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the same file on another unmodified CentOS 7 system. You will find that the missing section header is `[commands]`.

You should also look into what (or more likely *who*) possibly modified the file.

Comment: No idea how the file got modified, but removing and reinstalling yum-cron results in quite a different file, with the correct header. Thanks.

Comment: And another unmodified, newly setup CentOS 7 system had exactly the same issue.  So something funny is happening during initial install. Good thing I asked the question here because I had completely forgotten the resolution, got back here via Google :-)